# How can I tell what version of Android produced a system image?

Tags: android, computer-forensics, system-information

I have all the files and directories from a dead Android device. I have no more information about the device other than what was on the internal drive at the time it died. **What file would indicate what OS the now-dead device was running at the time it died?**

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you using the information for? Also, what sort of `Build` related data search have you done?

Comment: @Bonatti The OS is our fork of Android. I'm not on the OS team, but I'm tasked with figuring out how one of our devices died. Knowing the OS will help immensely.

Comment: From my search so far, I could only come up with `frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/os/ZygoteInit.java` would have the instructions to the boot, then with that, you could get what API was started ... yet, I was unable to check locally in my real device.

Comment: @Bonatti there is no `/frameworks` directory in this dump. Where did you find that info? If you're talking about the SDK, that's completely separate and never actually stored on the device.

Comment: [found here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/com/android/internal/os/ZygoteInit.java), however, I can only see the information being consumed, and not stored

Comment: @Bonatti That's the code you can use to compile your own OS, not what actually gets put onto the device. There are no `.java` files on Android devices.

Comment: Yes, but the `.class` file is unreadable. I am supposing you have a decompiler, and a good one... I myself am not aware of a file that holds the `version / build / etc. ` value. Doing some research locally and on the web, I did not came up with a better entry point to search, but it will be a manual search for a value that may not even be there.

Comment: @Bonatti Android doesn't work like regular java programs; there are no `.class` files, either.

Comment: Sorry, what I wanted to writte was `dex` files. Then again, the same principle remains, that they are compiled and compressed files, and are hard to read

Comment: @Bonatti alright, there are 56 `.dex` files. Which one do you say the OS version is in?

Comment: Can you see a `android/os/Build` one? In that one, there will be a refference to one (or a string directly) that may hold the actual version built.

Comment: @Bonatti here is the list of all dex files in the dump: http://pastebin.com/20U95Rvy